# Spring Cloud API Gateway Custom Filters with external API for Authorization

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway app with a custom filter to do Authorization in a route.
The route target is a blocking api also.
The Authorization filter fetches the permissions of the users from an external auth api using jwt token (blocking).
Then I am trying to check if the required permission is there , if not throw 401 .
But I am not getting the expected result as I am not able to figure how to handle the Mono from the permissions API.

The response is 200 even if the authorization is failing .
If the Authorization is allowed then I get the proper response from the downstream api in route.

**Filter Code**

```
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();          
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).get(0);
        //API to get permissions
        Mono<PermissionResponse> permissionsOfUser = getPermissions(authorizationHeader);

        return  permissionsOfUser.flatMap(pu->{
                    //doing permission check
                    if(!isAuthorized(pu)){
                        return   Mono.error(new AuthorizationException("Invalid"));
                    }else {
                        return chain.filter(exchange);
                    }
                })
                .doOnError(auth->this.onError(exchange,HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .doOnNext(auth->chain.filter(exchange));
    };
}
```

**Authorization Check**

```
private boolean isAuthorized(PermissionResponse permissionResponse) {
    if(permissionResponse.getFunctions().stream().map(f->f.getFuncKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains("EDIT_ACCESS")){
        log.info("Has Permissions");
        return true;
    }else{
        log.info("No Permissions");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**API Call to get permissions**

```
private Mono<PermissionResponse> getPermissions(String authorizationHeader) {
    return  webClientBuilder.build()
            .get()
            .uri(authPermissionsUrl)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationHeader)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(PermissionResponse.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate());
}
```

**Error Response**

```
private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, HttpStatus httpStatus)  {
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
    return response.setComplete();
}
```

**Routing**

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - name: CustomAuthorizationFilter
      routes:
        - id: app-id
          uri: http://myapi.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/getMyApiDetails/**
```

My thought is that I am not properly consuming the permission API Mono and not able to return the error from the filter.
I am new to webflux and not sure how to properly chain this.

log
2022-08-26 10:22:03.314 ERROR 16068 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [a7062490-6] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/getMyApiDetails/getDetails"

com.gateway.config.AuthorizationException: Invalid
at com.gateway.filters.CustomAuthorizationFilter.lambda$apply$0(CustomAuthorizationFilter.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):

Original Stack Trace:
at

```
com.gateway.filters.CustomAuthorizationFilter.lambda$apply$0(CustomAuthorizationFilter.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar:3.4.19]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar:3.4.19]
```

[image]

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm interested in it as well.